# Convert date to second from a reference - Python

Tags: python, datetime

time.time() gives current time in seconds from a given reference. Is there a mean to convert a date to a number of seconds since given reference?

I thought of calendar.timegm(), but I am not sure how to format the argument.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calendar.timegm` is the good approach. Just pass it the `utctimetuple()` output from your datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import calendar

dt = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
secs = calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())
print dt, secs
```

prints

```
2012-03-09 09:17:14.698500+00:00 1331284634
```

just to test it against the epoch:

```
print calendar.timegm(datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc).utctimetuple())
```

prints `0`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have current time X (seconds since the epoch), and you have a reference time Y. You want the number of seconds between them.

Use `mktime` to get seconds from the epoch to your reference point, and then just subtract X from Y, or Y from X (depending on which order you want).